# Batch file: escape a % character into a PostgreSQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, batch-file, escaping

I need to use a `%` character into a SQL query that I pass into a windows batch file. My issue is that this character is not taken into account.

```
towns=(12232, 12233)

for %%a in %towns% do (

    "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\pgsql2shp.exe" -h localhost -u thomas -P  password thomas_db "SELECT * FROM schema.table WHERE code like '%%a%'"

)
```

I get the following error:

> C:\batch><"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\pgsql2shp.exe" -h localhost -u thomas -P  password thomas_db "SELECT * FROM schema.table WHERE code like '12232'">
>   Initializing...
>   ERROR: Could not determine table metadata

The `LIKE '%%a%'` is interpreted as `LIKE '12232'` and should be as `LIKE '12232%'`.

Comment: `like '%#%a%' escape '#'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A double percent escapes a percent so double it up:

```
... WHERE code like '%%a%%%'"
```